# How to consolidate what you've learned?

Tags: soft-question, education

I'm reading through two books right now on the topics on quantum mechanics and particle physics. I'd like to know, how does one generally go back and **consolidate** what they've learned? There are various ways of reviewing for a subject, but physics for me has always been a bit tricky to review for. I'd really like to hear what some of the doctorate and master-degree students on stackexchange generally practice for consolidation and review of newly-learned material, before moving forward. Thanks again! I'd like to find a way to improve my own habits of self-study.

Comment: Much as I hesitate to criticise your questions yet again, this isn't a good fit for the main site because it's about the learning process not a question about physics. This could be usefully asked in [the Physics Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar), though the chat is quiet at the moment. The best time to ask would be from around 17:00 until midnight BST as the chat is livliest during that period.

Comment: Ok, I'll make sure to ask.

Answer (score 2):

There's "learning" and there's "understanding". The two are often completely separate. If you understand what you have learned you can apply it to real problems. Do the exercises which often come with textbooks